# Protocols Swift 2.2 Properties

Tags: swift, variables, protocols

I have this code

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var mustBeSettable: Int { get set }
    var doesNotNeedToBeSettable: Int { get }
}
```

And when implement the protocol in class

```
class example: SomeProtocol {

    doesNotNeedToBeSettable = 2

    func miFunc(word: String){

        doesNotNeedToBeSettable = 3
    }

}
```

Why I can modified the variable? because it is only **get**.

When can i use set? or set / get

Comment: Please explain better your question, every variable in an protocol need to be implemented in every class/struct,etc that implement it, the definition of when it's read-only or not is your decision in your declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that a `{get}` protocol property *may* be settable, but a `{get set}` protocol property *must* be settable.